# How to loop with CasperJS and find all tr id's

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to find a way to fetch one by one some id's and do for each of them some modification:

[image]

The above list of id's is not fixed so it can be that i have none or max. 15!

I was starting using repeat, but how I have a problem to fetch the next one (I am fetching always the first one). I assume because I can't use the variable count in the xp:

```
casper.then(function() {
    var numTimes = 6, count = 0;
    casper.repeat(numTimes, function(count) {
        var name = this.evaluate(function(count) {
        var xp = '//*[contains(@id, "connectedToNeType[' + count + ']")]'
        var element = __utils__.getElementByXPath(xp).getAttribute('id');
            return element;
        });
        this.echo(JSON.stringify(name));
    }, ++count);
});
```

Each tr id has the below code:

[image]

My goal at the end would be to fetch the check box id and select/un-select.
This part should be easy as soon i get the correct id name!

BTW, I did also tried to use `getElementByXPath` searching with text containing the text 'ABC_', because every of those have a title3 with 'ABC_xxx'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct indentation would have probably made the problem a little more apparent. `casper.repeat()` takes two arguments, but not three. The third argument is supposed to be passed into `casper.evaluate()`, so `count` is always `undefined` which means for some reason that the first element is matched.

```
casper.then(function() {
    var numTimes = 6, 
        count = 0;
    casper.repeat(numTimes, function() {
        var name = this.evaluate(function(count) {
            var xp = '//*[contains(@id, "connectedToNeType[' + count + ']")]'
            var element = __utils__.getElementByXPath(xp).getAttribute('id');
            return element;
        }, ++count);
        this.echo(JSON.stringify(name));
    });
});
```

Also, you don't need XPath to do that. CSS selectors support attribute selectors:

```
var name = this.evaluate(function(count) {
    var sel = '[id*="connectedToNeType[' + count + ']"]';
    var element = document.querySelector(sel).id;
    return element;
}, ++count);
```